# Подскажите как убрать эту ошибку при вызове данного метода?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: ViewController())
    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

При реализации данного кода в AppDelegrte 
У меня Xcode ругается что не видит  данный метод

Как исправить?

Comment: какой именно метод, текст ошибки?

Comment: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в `AppDelegate` свойство `var window: UIWindow?`

Comment: Спасибо заработало

Comment: @Anis в таком случае отметьте ответ как верный (поставьте галку)